# Conways game of life in Haskell

Tags: haskell, game-of-life

I started with Haskell some months ago, but didn't really use it since then. As a simple training I implemented Conways game of life. What/How could it be improved?

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State

data CellState = Dead | Alive deriving (Eq)
data Cell = Cell CellState Int deriving (Eq)
data Row = Row [Cell] Int deriving (Eq)
data Grid = Grid [Row]
data NextError = EmptyListError

type GridState a = State Grid a

instance Show Grid where
        show (Grid rows) = unlines $ map show rows

instance Show Row where
        show (Row cells n) = (show n) ++ ": " ++ (unwords $ map show cells)

instance Show Cell where
        show (Cell color _) = show color

instance Show CellState where
        show c = case c of
                Dead -> "_"
                Alive -> "#"

main::IO()
main = print $ run (execState initializeGrid (createGrid 20 20)) 100

run :: Grid -> Int -> [Grid]
run g n = scanl (\s f -> f s) g $ replicate n playRound

initializeGrid :: GridState ()
initializeGrid = do
        setPositionToColor 0 0 Alive
        setPositionToColor 1 1 Alive
        setPositionToColor 1 2 Alive
        setPositionToColor 2 0 Alive
        setPositionToColor 2 1 Alive
        setPositionToColor 4 4 Alive
        setPositionToColor 5 4 Alive
        setPositionToColor 6 4 Alive
        setPositionToColor 5 5 Alive
        setPositionToColor 5 4 Alive
        setPositionToColor 5 6 Alive

createGrid :: Int -> Int -> Grid
createGrid x y = Grid $ map createRow (take x [0,1..]) where
                        createRow = Row (map createCell (take y [0,1..]))
                        createCell = Cell Dead

setPositionToColor :: Int -> Int -> CellState -> GridState ()
setPositionToColor x y color = do
        grid <- get
        let rows = getRows grid
            cells = getCells (rows !! x)
            newState = Grid $ replaceListElement rows x $ Row (replaceListElement cells y $ Cell color y) x
        put newState

getCells :: Row -> [Cell]
getCells (Row c _) = c

getRows :: Grid -> [Row]
getRows (Grid r) = r

replaceListElement :: [a] -> Int -> a -> [a]
replaceListElement list position replacement =
        let (x, _:xs) = splitAt position list
        in x ++ replacement : xs

playRound :: Grid -> Grid
playRound (Grid rows) = Grid $ map (updateRow rows) rows

updateRow :: [Row] -> Row -> Row
updateRow rows row@(Row cells p) = Row (map (updateCell rows row) cells) p

updateCell :: [Row] -> Row -> Cell -> Cell
updateCell rows row cell@(Cell _ position) =
        let upperRowCells = getCells $ previous rows row
            upperCell = upperRowCells !! position
            lowerRowCells = getCells $ next rows row
            lowerCell = lowerRowCells !! position
            neighbourCells = [upperCell, lowerCell] ++
                getNextPrevious (getCells row) cell ++
                getNextPrevious upperRowCells upperCell ++
                getNextPrevious lowerRowCells lowerCell
            countLivingNeighbours = length $ filter (==Alive) $ map getCellColor neighbourCells
            isLiving = getCellColor cell == Alive
        in Cell (calcCellState isLiving countLivingNeighbours) position

getCellColor :: Cell -> CellState
getCellColor (Cell c _) = c

calcCellState :: Bool -> Int -> CellState
calcCellState living livingNeighbours
        | living && livingNeighbours < 2 = Dead
        | living && livingNeighbours <= 3 = Alive
        | living && livingNeighbours > 3 = Dead
        | not living && livingNeighbours == 3 = Alive
        | otherwise = Dead

getNextPrevious :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
getNextPrevious l e = [next l e, previous l e]

next :: Eq a => [a] -> a ->  a
next l@(x:_) e = case dropWhile (/= e) l of
                   (_:y:_) -> y
                   _ -> x

previous :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> a
previous l e = case takeWhile (/=e) l of
                [] -> last l
                x -> last x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things which came to my mind while reading your code:

- The `Show` instance for `CellState` might be a bit nicer by not writing out the `case` expression manually but rather using

  ```
  instance Show CellState where
      show Dead  = "_"
      show Alive = "#"
  ```
- You could shorten `initializeGrid` by using `mapM_`:

  ```
  initializeGrid :: GridState ()
  initializeGrid = mapM_ (\(x, y) -> setPositionToColor x y Alive)
      [(0,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(4,4),(5,4),(6,4),(5,5),(5,4),(5,6)]
  ```
- `take n [0,1..]` is the same as `[0,1..n]` (looking at `createGrid`).
- `callCellState` could be shortened by only explicitely testing the conditions determining whether the cell becomes (or remains) alive:

  ```
  calcCellState :: Bool -> Int -> CellState
  calcCellState living livingNeighbours
      | living && livingNeighbours `elem` [2,3] = Alive
      | not living && livingNeighbours == 3     = Alive
      | otherwise                               = Dead
  ```

On a more general note, seeing how long the `updateCell` function is and how you had to roll your own `next` and `previous` function I do suspect that lists are not the most appropriate data structure for this kind of problem. A [`vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) may be easier to work with.